# angularJs how to add href to $first

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am little confused on how to use `$first` to be honest, but what I am trying to do is set the first element of the repeat to have an `href` of `/school`.

```
<a class="list-group-item btn-warning" ng-repeat="schData in sortedSchools" 
             id = bla{{$index}} 
             ng-href={{in $first: "/school"}}>
    <h4>School Name: {{schData.schoolname}} </h4>
</a>
```

Could someone please explain how could I possibly to this, and also if someone knows of a good link to explain how to use `$first`?

Thank you in advance

Comment: the code does work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$first`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) is a boolean that evaluates to `true` if the repeated element is first in the iterator. You can use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) like this:

```
<a class="list-group-item btn-warning" 
            ng-repeat="schData in sortedSchools" 
            id="bla{{$index}}" 
            ng-href="{{$first ? '/school' : ''}}">
    <h4>School Name: {{schData.schoolname}} </h4>
</a>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/coc8816a/

With some more explanation on your specific issue, I may be able to assist you in better alternatives.

Comment: hey perfect thanks that's exactly what I needed. I am pulling a list of schools from a data base and I need to list them, but only the most recent school needs to be a link to another page, so this solution is perfect thank you